# How to create OS agnostic simple instruction to update global PATH?

Tags: bash, path

I need to instruct user to download software to location of their choice and then add the location path to the global PATH so that the user can invoke the software in any terminal.

The downloaded software works for Mac, Windows, Linux and ChromeOS.

It would be amazing to find a script or software that can automatically set the global PATH for the given OS, to make it easier for user and for me.

The complexity for mac/linux is to detect which profile to use (.bashrc, bash_profile, zshrc etc). May be all of them needs to be updated?

It seems the problem is pretty common, so there should be some simple solution.

Comment: `PATH` has the same format regardless of which operating system you are using. (assuming a POSIX-like shell). The only question is, what is the name of the directory that should be added to `PATH`? Ideally, *nothing* needs to be added: you install to one of the standard locations. If it's not a standard location, are *you* specifying the name of the directory, or does the user running the installer?

Comment: Yes, it is the same, but it needs to be updated in different places.
No installer, just script.
But it is interesting idea to may be redirect the command from a standard place to the directory where user downloaded the software.

Comment: What is standard location for mac?

Comment: $PATH and %PATH% are not exactly equal.  And I'm pretty sure that Windows 10/11 are not POSIX compliant.  This is usually handled by start up scripts, one for *nix like shells (.sh script) and another for Windows (.bat) script.  Usually making a temporary PATH change, before starting the program.